# Does applying with Stack Overflow Developer Jobs work?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

I apologize if this is not the proper Stack Exchange site to ask this question. I have applied to many jobs using Stack Overflow's Developer Jobs.

I apply to ones that I feel are a good fit, and I match the job's requirements. However, I have not once received any type of response, from anyone of them. I realize I may not be the applicant they need, but is no response typical? Am I just being lost in the pile? I do have a professional resume, and I always include a cover letter. Is my experience typical?

Answer (score 2):

@HunterX3, yes it does work.  I was hired through SO Jobs over a year ago.  It is typical for employers to not give any sort of response if you weren't chosen for an interview.

You could be getting lost in the pile - I wouldn't be surprised!  What you could do is find out who the hiring manager is for the company you are applying to.  Send a copy of your résumé to him/her along with a letter that states how your skills can help resolve some of the issues they may have with their software.  How do you find the hiring manager?  LinkedIn, or the company website, or someone who has worked there before.

I hope this helps.  Good luck!

Comment: So, you are saying that it doesn't work. As you are suggesting that he should look for the same company as on SO jobs elsewhere. huh?

Comment: No, @mega6382, it is simply an alternative!!